# Why does Bing webmaster tool's SEO analyzer complain about multiple <h1> tags?

Tags: seo, html5, bing-webmaster-tools

I used the Bing webmaster tool's SEO analyzer on my website, and it reported:

> There are multiple  tags on the page.

It recommends that there should only be one `<h1>` tag on the page.

The page is a listing of blog posts for a category. So each blog entry is structured like this.

```
<article>
    <header><h1><a>...</a></h1></header>
    <p>summary...</p>
</article>
<article>
    <header><h1><a>...</a></h1></header>
    <p>summary...</p>
</article>
<article>
    <header><h1><a>...</a></h1></header>
    <p>summary...</p>
</article>
<article>
    <header><h1><a>...</a></h1></header>
    <p>summary...</p>
</article>
```

How is this invalid? I thought this was the correct way to describe a post in HTML5.

Comment: You are using `head` elements in `article`, which is not allowed. You probably mean `header`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change your code which is valid, it's just because SEO analyzer from Bing is late and doesn't take into account HTML5 semantic.

Comment: oh wow what a surprise. A Microsoft tool that isn't following standards. thanks.

Comment: Yes, many SEO tools are late about HTML5 semantic.

Comment: I switched back to this as the right answer. Inspecting many popular websites showed that `<h1>` is used in `<article>` tags all the time. I think the problem is that I'm missing a `<section>` tag.

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini: don't forget it's not because SEO tools or search engines are late considering HTML5 that you don't have to use semantic markup. In a close future, SEO tools and search engines will be compatible with HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, it's correct (as Zistoloen said), but logically it isn't. `<h1>` tags are supposed to be used as the title for your entire page, which isn't the case here. Using multiple `<h1>` tags sends mixed signals to search engines and it'll be less obvious for them to know what your page is really about.

I would put the category title in `<h1>` tags and the article titles in `<h2>` tags. This way, it's obvious that your page is a category overview and that the articles are logically placed under that category.

You don't have to change it, but since search engines like the structure and use it to see what your page is about, I would http://webdesign.about.com/od/seo/a/why_use_h1_for_seo.htm is an interesting read.

Comment: that's a good answer. I agree with you on that.

Comment: It’s perfectly logical. Each sectioning element may have a heading. The level of this heading is irrelevant, only the nesting of the sectioning element matters. That way you can copy-and-paste whole sections without having to adjust the heading levels. HTML5 could have introduced a `h` element, but it didn’t because of backwards compatibility, so it re-used `h1`-`h6`, while it ignores the level (for the sectioning element heading only, that is).

Comment: The title element should be used for the title of the whole page.  Heading elements are not meant to contain page titles.